# Run a program at every windows startup before logon screen

Tags: vb.net, windows, automation, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

Hoping its a simple one.

I need to run a vb.net program at Windows startup before the logon screen is even displayed.
It will require no input and will be a console only program that checks a few system settings with values stored in a mysql database and updates any mismatched settings, such as IP information or local username's

I know of the Run and RunOnce reg keys, but I believe these will execute on user login, which is not suitable for what I require.

I already utilize the SetupComplete.cmd scripts on first boot following OS deploy to handle a fair bit of the initial setup, but now I need to ensure that the settings applied on first boot are maintained following each reboot.

Any help appriciated!

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just run the vb script with a scheduled task (windows task scheduler) and use the trigger "at startup".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you know if this scheduled task persist following a sysprep?

Comment: @John possibly it depends on what credentials you are using to fire the task.  If you use a built in admin account with a password that won't change on each system I believe it will work, but if your using a domain account or a different username on each system the task will travel with each image but you will need to modify the credentials on each pc.